# How to wrap PDO try catch exception handlers into multiple classes

Tags: php, class, oop, exception, pdo

Lets say, that I have a class with many functions to access mysql databases, and within this class, there are many methods that use

```
function one(){
    try{
      ...
    }catch(PDOException $e){
       return $e->getMessage()
    }
}
```

Now, since I have close to the 10 methods applying the same exception, I would like to know if there is any other way to do only once, for all methods, instead of repeating the same process over and over.

I could obviously, do this upon instantiating the class,

like

```
$Object = new foo();

try{
    echo $Object->methodFoo(); 
}catch(PDOException $e){
       return $e->getMessage()
}
```

But, this is not what I am looking for.

If there is any other clever way to do this, It would be nice to know.

Comment: Run all the actual queries through one method that actually does the PDO commands / holds the only try/catch.  I don't know what your class looks like but I use a PDO wrapper class which lets me have catch all my exceptions for all my classes (I use a modified version of :http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/)

Comment: @hendr1x please **don't** tell people to use that crap. That class not only introduces possible SQL injection vulnerability (due to emulated prepares), it also completely negate any benefits you would gain from preparing query one and executing multiple times. **That library IS HARMFUL.**

Comment: tereško : this is the second time you call me out and didn't give me any helpful data at all.  I would truly appreciate it if you could help me learn oppose to just saying I'm doing something bad.  If the wrapper utilizes native PDO how could it introduce SQL injection?  Your comment about reusing prepared queries is pretty weak. How often are you rerunning the same query and how much overhead is really adding? It would take 10 minutes to code a caching system into the class if you want to and I'm pretty sure that mysql will cache the queries anyway. Lastly what db library do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are millions of performance reasons not to do this, but in theory at least you could hide all of your methods by making them private then use the overload`__call()` to call them with the `try { } catch { }` block in that.

Something like this maybe:

```
class TheClass
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $result= null;
        try {
            $result= $this->$name($arguments);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Ooops: ".$ex->getMessage();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function one() {
        return 'hello';
    }

    private function two() {
        // Intentional error
        throw new Exception('Don\'t call two!');
    }
}

$foo= new TheClass();
echo $foo->one();
echo $foo->two();
```

**EDIT** Looking at the suggestion by hendr1x - moving all of the actual PDO code into a single function and putting the catch in that is probably a much better answer!